# live regions not working with dynamic page title - angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, accessibility, single-page-application

Angular changes the view so that the page title changes, but screen readers can't read it, so I tried to use live regions, but that  doesn't work.

`<title ng-bind="title" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">Title here</title>`

I want to know the reason why live regions not working in this case? 
I don't need any solution to make user know the page is changed and content also

Comment: Just in case, does it work with `aria-live="polite"`?

Comment: Relevant definition: [live region](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/terms#def_liveregion) (is title a "perceivable region of a web page that (is) typically updated" when it's only updated when "page" changes in good ol' web "sites"?). Other roles you could try: [special cases live regions](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-wai-aria-practices-20130307/#chobet) (I don't know what is their support in page content - element in body-, not to say as a title element)

Comment: @FelipeAls unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<title>` element does not allow any ARIA nor `role` attributes: http://w3c.github.io/html-aria/#el-title

The two HTML validators ([Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/) and [Nu Html Checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/)) do not flag use of those attributes as an error. Not flagging those appears to be a bug in the validators and I will file one once I gather more details and build a reduced test case. Alternatively, if this should be supported, then I can file a bug against the ARIA spec. If you can provide more detail and context for adding support to ARIA that will help.

In the meantime, did some testing:

1. NVDA / FF does not appear to support `aria-live` on `<title>` at all.
2. JAWS / IE11 does appear to support `aria-live` on `<title>` but inconsistently. It also does not announce that it is the page title that has changed.
3. I do not have VoiceOver handy to test. I did not test in Narrator, TalkBack, nor Orca.

I made a CodePen test page:

- The URL where you may edit: http://codepen.io/aardrian/pen/XpqZMB?editors=1010
- The URL that excludes an CodePen cruft (for testing): http://s.codepen.io/aardrian/debug/XpqZMB

Comment: I tested it before I ask on Chrome & Firefox with NVDA and ChromeVox and doesn't appear any support.

so that I asked the question to know the reason I know the live regions only work when page content updated and in this case the title updates and the live regions not work.

Comment: ChromeVox is not a very good screen reader. Its use is mostly for testing. JAWS has some support, but it is spotty. But the reason it does not work well is because it is not intended to work.